# Jasmine test for checkbox change handler function in angular 12

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

I am trying to write simple test function for check box change, but I am unabled to run it.
The error is Spec has no expectations. and the handler function is not covered in code coverage,.

template:
`<input type="checkbox" (change)="handleChange($event)">`

handler function:

```
handleChange(event:any){
     if(event.target.checked){
        this.myVariable= true;
     }else{
       this.myVariable = false;
     }
}
```

Test case:

```
it('checkbox change should set the myVariable value',fakeAsync(()=>{
 myCheckBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myCheckBox'));
 spyOn(component, 'handleChange'); 
 myCheckBox.triggerEventHandler('change',{target: myCheckBox.nativeElement});
 tick();
 fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(component.myVariable).toBetrue;
}));
```

How should I write Jasmine test case to check this function and also cover if statement.

Comment: You need to 1) find the input in your tests, 2-a) pass a mocked event containing target.checked to fullfill the first condition and 2-b) pass another mocked event containing event.target.checked at false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test seems good but the issue is that `spyOn` just creates a spy on the method and returns undefined and you lose implementation details. To keep the implementation details (meaning call the actual function as well), you can use `.and.callThrough()`

```
it('checkbox change should set the myVariable value',fakeAsync(()=>{
 myCheckBox = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#myCheckBox'));
 // change this line
 const handleSpy = spyOn(component, 'handleChange').and.callThrough(); 
 // change this line as well to mock the object
 myCheckBox.triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { checked: true });
 tick();
 fixture.detectChanges();
 expect(component.myVariable).toBeTrue();
 expect(handleSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
}));
```