# Change Radio button value Angular Jasmine Testing

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have two radio buttons, first one checked. Now, in my test file, I want to check the second radio button and then continue testing further. I am not finding a way to do so.

Following is my radio button:

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
      <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioButton" (change)="some_func(true)" checked>
      <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">Radio1</label>
 </div>
 <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
       <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="RadioButton" (change)="some_func(false)">
       <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio2">Radio2</label>
</div>
```

I tried the following to change my radio button value, but it doesn't work :

```
let options: DebugElement[] = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('input[type="radio"]'));
options[1].triggerEventHandler('change', { target: options[1].nativeElement });
```

Can someone help me here, how can I make the second radio button checked?

Answer (score 0):

Cypress has its own api for interacting with elements [link](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/interacting-with-elements)

```
        <div
            class="form-check form-check-inline"
            data-cy="form-check-label"
          >
            <input type="checkbox" />
...
```

`cy.get('[data-cy=form-check-label]').find('input').check()`

Imagine div wrapped your input, you would use `find()` on its child input and call `check()`. Use `data-cy=some_name` to give your elements cypress specific selectors, then you know if element attributes change e.g class your tests won't be affected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find a solution here :

[Jasmine test for checkbox change handler function in angular 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68410322/jasmine-test-for-checkbox-change-handler-function-in-angular-12)

- You would need to run detectChanges()
- You can access both your radio with :

`options[0].triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { checked: true } });`

`options[1].triggerEventHandler('change', { target: { checked: true } });`